# Error/exception handling in imported Python module/library that uses threading

Tags: python, exception, pyserial

I'm using python library which in turn use pyserial to communicate with a device. From time to time I got exception that originates from pyserial, and was mentioned on SO couple of times:

> ERROR:read failed: device reports readiness to read but returned no
> data (device disconnected or multiple access on port?) Traceback (most
> recent call last):   File
> "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 490, in
> read
> 'device reports readiness to read but returned no data ' serial.serialutil.SerialException: device reports readiness to read
> but returned no data (device disconnected or multiple access on port?)

That error is generated by the said library, and I can route it to log file with logger settings. With that exception pyserial (and hence the library) obviously looses connection with serial port.

What I want to do is to restore that connection upon receiving that error. But the library uses threading and provides me only with the callback function upon receiving serial communication events. So I believe, there is no way to use try/except, especially given that the library seems to handle that exception to log error.

So my thought is to be notified somehow when the logger receives that error, and to .close() and .open() connection. But how to  get that notification?

Or is there some better way?

Answer (score 0):

The way I see for now:

```
old_factory = logging.getLogRecordFactory()
global record, record_msg
ERROR = False
record_msg = ''
serial_error = "read failed: device reports readiness to read but returned no data " + \
               "(device disconnected or multiple access on port?)"

def record_factory(*args, **kwargs):
    global record, ERROR, record_msg
    record = old_factory(*args, **kwargs)
    if record.levelname=="ERROR":
        ERROR = True
        record_msg = str(record.msg)
```

So, from the new `record_factory` I can set flags and do some other actions.